# Getting Fn hotkeys to work in windows 8 sony vaio laptop, originally built for windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, laptop, drivers, sony-vaio

I have made a clean install on a Sony Vaio laptop (VPCF22L1E/B), which originally had Windows 7.  After installing the drivers for Windows 8 that Sony has provided, I realized that the <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>f#</kbd> keys did not work.

So I searched the internet for a possible solution. I've read that I need a driver called Sony Vaio Event service, which is available for Windows 7, but not Windows 8. I tried installing the Windows 7 driver in compatibility mode, but it didn't work. Is there any workaround I can try?

Comment: [Sony Community](http://community.sony.com/t5/Windows-8/Windows-8-Upgrade-FN-Keys-and-Stamina-Speed-switch/m-p/37939#M304) has a pretty big forum in regards to this, have you searched it for possible solutions?

Comment: I would look for a newer version of the driver for one of Sony's newer Vaio products.  Without the driver there isn't much you can do.

Comment: Well, the newer version thing did not work. I've posted a question on the Sony Community, but the problem is that the model of laptop I have is available only in some European countries. I've e-mailed the Turkish Sony Support staff, but I expect no answer. I'll call them in a few days, if things don't work out.